# HOW TO ACCESS SQLITE DATABASE IN BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

Iam trying to open database but iam getting error my code is has follows

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
     SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Cursor c;
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from mytable",null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name;
        name=c.getString(0);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Today is " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



     }

    }
```

Error:

```
MODE_PRIVATE can not be resolved to a variable
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` to access static Constant from `Context` class:

```
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

***Suggestion:***

Because `BroadcastReceiver` duration is very less so it's not possible to perform long running operation in `onReceive`. so use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to perform database operation when broadcast  receive.